# Outlining methods in Japanese

Tags: translation

In English, when building a shelf, for example, the instruction booklet will go along the lines of "Step 1. ~~~~. Step 2. ~~~~ etc."

In Japanese, I know that you can explain methods by going まずは、それで and ついに but is there a Japanese equivalent to "steps"? What if I wanted to say "There are 3 steps you have to follow"?

Answer (score 3):

You can use ステップ or 手順【てじゅん】.

> - 手順1, 手順2, 手順3, ...
> - ステップ1, ステップ2, ステップ3, ...
> - Xをするには3つの手順が必要です。
> - Xをするには3ステップが必要です。 (You can use ステップ as a counter.)

Also note that the proper word for 'finally' in this context is 最後【さいご】に, not ついに. ついに means 'at last'.